# Почему превышается количество запросов к геокодеру?

Tags: yandex-maps-api

В документациии я читал, что если от геокодера идёт слишком много запросов (>25000), то api блокируется на сутки. В моём сервисе нет такого количества запросов, тем не менее я время от времени получаю в консоли такое сообщение об ошибке:

> 429 (Too Many Requests)

При этом через вкладку браузера network видно, что никакие запросы *не отправляются* из моего сервиса к yandex maps api. **Это странность номер 1.**

Кроме того, после получения вышеописанного сообщения об ошибке я обычно жду секунд 40-60 и повторно обращаюсь к геокодеру. теоретически он не должен отработать, так как получается, что я забанен на сутки, но он отрабатывает без проблем. **Это странность номер 2.**

Всё вышеописанное повторяется в теяение дня многократно. Объясните мне пожалуйста что происходит и можно ли заставить геокодер работать без сбоев?

Comment: С такими вопросами лучше обращаться в техподдержку сервиса, вряд ли тут вам смогут помочь. Статистику в сутки вы должны видеть по своему API-ключу в Кабинете разработчика.

Comment: Если Вам нормально отвечают через 40 секунд, значит это не бан на сутки, а просто сбой на сервере. Ну в смысле пришло очень много запросов к серверу от других пользователей, сервер не справляется и Вам отдает диагностику, что он занят.

Comment: @pepsicoca1 на самом деле это может быть бан за превышение лимитов, если использовать сервис без ключа (ключи обязательны, поэтому у анонимных пользователей могут возникать артефакты). В целом если передаётся корректный API-ключ, такой статус получить нельзя.